# dynamically create routes - rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, routes

I currently have three levels of pages, first, second and third levels. They each have a reference e.g:

`/firstlevel`

`/firstlevel/secondlevel`

`/firstlevel/secondlevel/thirdlevel`

every third level page only links to one second level page and every second level page only links to one first level page. However at the moment, you could enter any first second and third reference and the third level page would still show up. I need some validation somewhere so that there is only one way to get to the third level page; by using the correct first and second level references.

This is what I have in my routes file:

```
match "/:reference" => "service#firstlevel"
match "/:reference/:reference" => "service#secondlevel"
match "/:reference/:reference/:reference" => "service#thirdlevel"
```

Comment: Are your references unique? If yes it is straight forward. Please add more details.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand you completely.. but each page has a unique reference, yes.

Comment: Then at service#thirdlevel action check for valid first and second level references and only if they exist display third level page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Added this into my controller for each method:

```
if request.fullpath == ("/#{@s.firstlevel.reference}/#{@s.reference}")

else
  render :action => "error404"
```

Probably not the best way to do things.

Answer (score 0):

This will give you /companies/peoples/jobs

```
resource :companies do
   resource :people do
     resource :jobs
   end
end
```

at your routes